# Comparing data in two mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, compare, procedure

I have two mysql database. I have to compare column data of one table in the first database with the column data of the second database. In both databases , table name and column names are same. I have to find the common data.  The column is a varchar field. But the problem is "newyork times" and "times newyork" and "newyork" should be considered as common. I am not able to generate the sql query. This is the procedure i have tried

```
drop procedure if exists test;
delimiter #
create procedure test()
begin

declare v_max int unsigned default 243;
declare v_counter int unsigned default 1;
declare pName varchar(255);

start transaction;
while v_counter < v_max do
select t.property_name from t.property where t.property_id=v_counter into pName;
SELECT distinct b.property.property_name,b.property.property_id from b.property where    b.property.property_name like '%'+pName+'%'
set v_counter=v_counter+1;
end while;
commit;
end #

delimiter ;
```

Is it possible to compare likewise?

Comment: "he problem is "newyork times" and "times newyork" and "newyork" should be considered as common" -- that's a very different problem than simply comparing databases.  How do you define what is equal?

Comment: @Joe That is the problem I am facing. I want to know if it is possible to compare like that or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell MySQL to do such a vague comparison. It can't know which of the following should be considered "the same"

- newyork times
- new york times
- t
- york

If you have a limited number of "mistakes", you could normalise them in the lookup

```
WHERE t.property_name = REPLACE(v.property_name, 'new york times', 'new york')
```

But of course that *very* quickly becomes unmanageable.

Can you add a new column, even temporarily?  Then you could do some sort of cleansing of the data in a set of pre-passes.

```
UPDATE t
SET cleanpropertyname = 'new york times' 
WHERE property_name IN ('new york times', 'new york', 'nyt')
```

Comment: I am not trying to find mistakes. I am trying to find similar names from two columns of the two database. Say in one database it is stored as "NewYork times" and in the other database it is stored as "times NewYork". Both should be equal. Anyways thanks for your reply

Comment: And I've said that's not possible. The point I'm making is that you might be able to normalise your data, *then* do the compare. I quoted the work mistakes on purpose, to indicate I didn't mean errors, as such, but things that need to be made the same. You **cannot** ask a computer to compare things that "are a bit similar in an un-defined way". If you have a specific set of linguistic rules, say so, and give more examples. (Thanks for the silent downvotes btw, whoever left that without explaining why)